# Accumulators in python

Tags: python, while-loop, accumulator

I have to make an accumulator that counts the number of entries a user uses to guess a random number. I have all the while statements figured out but I can't get the piece that counts how many entries it took. Thanks for any help!

```
import random
secretNumber = random.randint(1,100)
secretNumber = int(secretNumber)
print("Guess a number between 1 and 100!")
number = input("Your guess: ")
number = int(number)
tries = 1
while number != secretNumber:
    if number > secretNumber:
        print("Too high!")
        number = input("Your guess: ")
        number = int(number)
    if number < secretNumber:
        print("Too low!")
        number = input("Your guess: ")
        number = int(number)
while number == secretNumber:
    print("You got it in",tries,"tries")
    break
```

the part I need help with is implementing the tries accumulator after the break

Comment: You can feel free to add your code here - it makes it much easier to tell what is going and how best we can help :)

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you want to ask is when you `print tries`, what are you getting?
Effectively, you will see you are always getting 1.

Because, you didn't increment. You didn't add as user keeps guessing.

Generally, you can write `tries = tries + 1` for each guess.

```
tries = 1
while number != secretNumber:
    if number > secretNumber:
        print("Too high!")
        tries = tries + 1      # here is the addition
        number = input("Your guess: ")
        number = int(number)
    if number < secretNumber:
        print("Too low!")
        tries = tries + 1      # here is the addition
        number = input("Your guess: ")
        number = int(number)
while number == secretNumber:
    print("You got it in",tries,"tries")
    break
```

This code still has some problem. The 2nd loop doesn't make sense. A loop sounds like loop. It keeps running until a condition is met or someone (you) interrupts it and tells it to exit.

If user found the number, then `while number !- secretNumber` will become `False` right?
It will exit the first loop. Hence, you can skip the second loop and congratulate the user.

Another minor thing is the double `if` statements.
 `if` statements are expensive. Computer has to test to guess right. But either way, there is a different way to do multiple conditions.

```
if condition1 met:
    do this
elif condition2 met:
    do this
elif condition3 met:
    do this
elif more....
else:   # optional, but encourage, this is a default fallback case
    do this
```

If `number > secretNumber` is `True`, then you don't need to test `number < secretNumber` in theory. It makes the code cleaner and logically sound by adapting `if .. elif .. else`

```
import random
secretNumber = random.randint(1,100)
secretNumber = int(secretNumber)
print("Guess a number between 1 and 100!")
number = input("Your guess: ")
number = int(number)
tries = 1
while number != secretNumber:
    if number > secretNumber:
        print("Too high!")
        tries = tries + 1      # here is the addition
        number = input("Your guess: ")
        number = int(number)
    elif number < secretNumber:
        print("Too low!")
        tries = tries + 1      # here is the addition
        number = input("Your guess: ")
        number = int(number)
print("You got it in",tries,"tries")
# another way to print is
# print("You got it in %s tries" % tries)
# print("You got it in {t} tries".format(t=tries))
```

For beginners, use `print` to help debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the line

```
tries += 1
```

in the loop- this line increases the `tries` variable by 1.

I also took the liberty of shortening it by removing part of it from the if statement, and removed the second while loop (since the loop always occurs exactly once there's no reason to put a loop there):

```
while number != secretNumber:
    tries += 1
    if number > secretNumber:
        print("Too high!")
    if number < secretNumber:
        print("Too low!")
    number = input("Your guess: ")
    number = int(number)
print("You got it in",tries,"tries")
```

Comment: ok great! thanks so much...what does the += operator do exactly (in general) just in case I have to explain it to my teacher

Comment: @user1880690: It is equivalent to `tries = tries + 1`

Comment: Note this doesn't work when you input something random like `'foobar'` or something.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
i = 0
rand_num = random.randint(1, 100)
while True:
    i += 1
    try:
        guess = int(input('Guess the number: ')
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid input, try again')
        continue
    if guess < rand_num:
        print('Too low, try again')
    elif guess > rand_num:
        print('Too high, try again')
    else:
        print('You got it in ', tries, ' tries!')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just add to the number of tries if you get it wrong:

```
...
while number != secretNumber:
    tries += 1
    if number > secretNumber:
        print("Too high!")
...
```

Also, at the end instead of this:

```
while number == secretNumber:
    print("You got it in",tries,"tries")
    break
```

you can just use this:

```
print("You got it in",tries,"tries")
```

because it would only get to this point if you get the number right.

Another thing, tries should initially be equal to 0, no one, because at the beginning you tried 0 times, not 1.

Comment: It depends on the context. But if you think about it, I am told to guess a number, and the first time I got it right. How many attempts? One. So OP is right. Again, depends on the story.

Answer (score -1):

You want to add the extra line `tries += 1` in the while loop. What this does is add 1 to tries every guess. So then your code would be:

```
import random
secretNumber = random.randint(1,100)
secretNumber = int(secretNumber)
print("Guess a number between 1 and 100!")
number = input("Your guess: ")
number = int(number)
tries = 1
while number != secretNumber:
    if number > secretNumber:
        print("Too high!")
        number = input("Your guess: ")
    number = int(number)
    if number < secretNumber:
        print("Too low!")
        number = input("Your guess: ")
        number = int(number)
while number == secretNumber:
    print("You got it in",tries,"tries")
    break
```